# Unable to access BIOS, black screen, beeps

Tags: ubuntu, boot, motherboard, bios

Recently changed to Ubuntu, wanting to try out and learn the command line, etc. Then after about 2 weeks I wanted to change to a harder Linux distribution, like arch, so I proceeded to make a boot able USB and put it in. My computer was unable to find it in the BIOS, so I played around with some settings in it.

Now when I try to start my computer all I see is a black screen and hear 1 beep and then 3 fast beeps following the first beep. I can SOMETIMES start and enter Ubuntu, without any problems, but some times it just continues to an infinite black screen that doesn't change no matter what I press and do. I got an asus boot menu, and I think I change some setting where it stood "Windows something something". Can someone give me a solution or have any idea on what I changed?

Comment: What is your computer model? (e.g. HP Pavilion dv7-6c43cl)

Comment: I'm not too good with computers but I'll do my best to provide with info:
CPUs: 4
Vendor: AMD
Model Name: AMD A10-68000K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *general* [BIOS codes](http://www.bioscentral.com/beepcodes/awardbeep.htm), 1 long beep followed by 3 short is due to a **deficient video card** (maybe a contact failure if you can sometimes boot your OS properly).

Comment: Do you know any tutorial on how to fix this? Or do I just google how to do it and just debuild my computer?